# Django custom authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework in my app. I need authentication but not the default one. I have a model:

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(...)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(...)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(...)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

Worker sends messages through my API to view WorkerView which inherits from Django REST Framework's APIView. Token is send in request's header:

```
class WorkerView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        # some not important code
```

I have an authenticating method:

```
def authenticate(request):
    try:
        ip = request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR", None)
        token = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION", None)
    ...
```

I thought about two solutions:

1. Make a mixin class and inherit it in my WorkerView:

   ```
   class WorkerView(AuthenticationMixin, APIView)
       ...
   ```
2. Make a class decorator from my authenticate method and use it like this:

   ```
   @authenticate
   class WorkerView(APIView)
   ```

But in both cases I need to pass request argument to authenticate method. 
How to do that? Or maybe there's a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't You create a custom authentication class as defined here? 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication

Comment: Because I need to split users between those which log with login/password and those which use token. And I don't want to mofidy/extend User model. Instead I want to authorize my model objects, not User objects. I do know and I used custom authentication. If I want to use it I wouldn't ask.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. You can use as many authentication classes at once as You want, and creating a custom authentication class is a good way to accomplish Your task.